# PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI returns twice the same contact

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

in my code below, i am trying to get all contacts with a specific phone number.

however it looks like i always get some of the contacts id more then once.
specifically i have 2 contacts with the same phone number, and i get 3 contact Id's. one of them twice (the same ID)

any ideas?

thanks

```
Cursor contactLookupCursor =  
localContentResolver.query(
    Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(requestedPhone)), 
                    new String[] {PhoneLookup._ID}, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);

if (contactLookupCursor != null)
{
    System.out.println("contactLookupCursor.getCount = "+contactLookupCursor.getCount()); // here i get 3
    if(contactLookupCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            int ColumnIndex = contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID);
            if(ColumnIndex >= 0)
            {
                String contactId = contactLookupCursor.getString(ColumnIndex);
                System.out.println("contactId="+contactId);// here i get 12 then 13 then 13 again
            }
        }
        while (contactLookupCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    contactLookupCursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**If** you provide a **non-normalized phone** number to PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI then it will be **matched at two positions** in the data record table of phone numbers.

```
1 match for number with column "number" in record.
1 match for normalized_number with column "normalized_number" in record.
```

**If** you provide `number = "+49177123456"` then **number == normalized_number** .

In **this case** PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI will **only search** in the **"normalized_number" column** of the phone table.

---

You can alternatively use **CommonDataKinds.Phone** instead of PhoneLookup.

**This way you don't get duplicate results whether the provided phone number is normalized or not:**

```
String number = "0177123456";
Uri uri =     Uri.withAppendedPath(android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(number));
Cursor rcursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                                        new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID },
                                        null,null,null);
```

I guess the strange behavior of PhoneLookup is a bug .

But **maybe PhoneLookup is more performant** than CommonDataKinds.Phone:

> Class Overview: [...] This query is highly optimized. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html

There is no such statement for CommonDataKinds.Phone.

Comment: I always provide a non-normalized number (i.e. only the number you'd dial if you were local) and without leading zeros. So you can imagine that the number I want to look up is incomplete. However, `PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI` still finds the correct contact. Is it because the resulting query is `LIKE %number%` ?

Comment: I've tried removing digits from the right side of the phone number, and `PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI` then  no longer finds a match. It seems that the underlying query is `LIKE %number` because I can lose several digits from the left and it makes a match still.

Comment: CommonDataKinds.Phone causes E/execption: Invalid column number

Comment: 2 important things to know about `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI`: 1.When the contact is saved with national phone number and you search the international phone number that matches it, it might not find it on some devices. 2. It can return you results if you search by a partial number, even if it's just 3 digits that you query...